# android httpclient

Tags: android, httpclient

How to transfer a 50mb file to web server using httppost.
When trying to transfer the file it shows out of memory error.
can we use chuncked encoding? how? give some code snippets.

Thank you.

**Edit:**
Here's the code:

```
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(f), -1);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octect-stream"); 
reqEntity.setChunked(true);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

Comment: What method are you using now?

Comment: InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(f), -1); reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octect-stream"); reqEntity.setChunked(true); httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

Answer (score 4):

Use `InputStreamEntity` as it does not load the whole file in memory. Do something like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/upload");

File file = new File("/path/to/myfile");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(fileInputStream, file.length());

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

if (responseEntity != null) {
  responseEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks., but how can i get the file at web server (struts2)

Comment: Use Struts File Upload Interceptor: https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/file-upload-interceptor.html